# How to convert a tuple of numbers to float in F#?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a tuple of numbers:

```
let mynum = (3, 5, 8.9, 45, 127.3)
```

It's mixed `int` with `float`. In order to do calculations like **average**, I have to convert them to `float`. How to do the conversion?

Comment: Almost seems like you should use a different collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did the input turn out in this format? Tuples aren't supposed to be used in this way; they are intended for combinations of a few objects, which are strongly and *independently* typed.

The type of a tuple changes with its length, so there is no straightforward way to perform sequence operations on them. They are not compatible with `seq<'T>` anyway, since they the types of their components are unrelated. *There is no average function for tuples, and if there were, it would have to be overloaded for all possible arities (number of components).*

You might want to import the data into another collection, such as [a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx), a [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx), an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx), or [another type of sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233209.aspx), and have the importer handle conversions where necessary. For example, if the input were a list of strings (as taken from a text file or such), `System.Double.Parse` or, as pointed out by ildjarn in the comments, the [`float` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353752.aspx), can be used to turn them into floats:

```
let input = ["3"; "5"; "8.9"; "45"; "127.3"]
List.map float input
```

This returns `[3.0; 5.0; 8.9; 45.0; 127.3]`, which is of type `float list`: an [immutable, singly-linked list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx) of double-precision floats.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm new to F#, at the beginning, it seems a little constrained of not being able to add int to float. After reading the answers, I know that I'm wrong with the type. Thanks again for point out the `System.Double.Parse` and the documentation link.

Comment: `List.map float input` would work as well, using the [`float` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353752.aspx) rather than the `float` type in this context.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how did you end up with that tuple, I would advise to review your design. I personally consider tuples of more than 4 elements a smell, may be a record with named elements would be a best fit.

Anyway you can convert it easily to a list of float and then calculate the average:

```
let mynum = (3, 5, 8.9, 45, 127.3)
let inline cnv (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) = [float x1; float x2; float x3; float x4; float x5]
let lst = cnv mynum // float list = [3.0; 5.0; 8.9; 45.0; 127.3]
List.average lst    // float = 37.84
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wrong with the type tuple. I wish I could mark both of the two answers as the right answer. _consider tuples of more than 4 elements a smell, may be a record with named elements would be a best fit._ this is really a good point!